# What conditions are necessary for lastInsertId to work

Tags: postgresql, pdo

I'm trying to wrap my head around PDO. How come $lastid doesn't output anything?

```
function renderRoot($db){
    $sql = "INSERT INTO nodes (name) VALUES ('/');";
    $response = $db->query($sql);
    $lastid = $db->lastInsertId();
    echo $lastid;
    return;
}
```

The code adds a value to the table and it has an column called id, that aoutincrements.

Here is my sql(postgresql):

```
$nodetable = "create table nodes (
    id serial primary key,
    parentid integer references nodes(id ),
    name varchar
);";
```

Comment: Does the table have an auto-increment column? Did the insert succeed?

Comment: the inser succeeded. I'll updated the question with the sql.

Comment: Use `INSERT ... RETURNING ...` instead. This `lastInsertId` stuff is modeled after mysql and not the best choice with postgres.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In postgresql, lastInsertId() take an argument, in your case, the name of the sequence, i.e. nodes_id_seq

```
$lastid = $db->lastInsertId('nodes_id_seq');
```

Otherwise it will return the last oid, if any.

Comment: worht noting is that nodes is my database and id is the column. Thanks!